# Shortest wide-body route from Frankfurt

Tags: air-travel, factoids, aircraft, fra

What is the shortest passenger route served by wide-body aircraft (i.e. B747, B777, A330, A340, A380 etc.), preferably on daily basis, preferably by Lufthansa (but any airline flying from Frankfurt will work for me).

The shortest one, I found, is FRA-IKA (Frankfurt-Teheran) direct flight with less than 5 hours of flying, served by Lufthansa on daily basis with B747.

Comment: I believe this was a temporary route: [A380 from Frankfurt Airport to London Heathrow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58AryokIROE). You may search from Frankfurt to Paris, Amsterdam, Milan, Madrid as they are potential candidates.

Comment: Question narrowed to A380 [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/78030/15281).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To my knowledge the shortest wide body scheduled passenger service from Frankfurt is the British Airways flight BA0903 to London Heathrow which is operated by a Boeing 767.

For a short time after the introduction of the A380 at BA, this route was served by an A380 to allow more crews to familiarize themselves with the aircraft in a short time.

Answer (score 5):

LAN flies FRA-MAD route on a 787 with prices as low as 200-300 euro return in business.

In general, you could search with matrix using a one-way search such as:

Departing from: FRA::N / aircraft t:300 t:310 t:330 t:340 t:350 t:380 t:747 t:767 t:777 t:787
Destination: LON,PAR,GVA,MAD

Adjust according to desired aircraft and destination.

Comment: Trying to avoid making this a shopping question, but are you sure -- 2 euros return business class ticket sounds like something completely unbelievable to me. Far, far below cheapest cheap flight prices. Sounds like beating unbeatable Ryanair! :>

Comment: @trejder read as 2 to 3 hundred

Comment: @trejder Your version is clearer.

Comment: Now that it's fixed you should both deleted your comments. I'll delete this one in a couple of minutes too.

Answer (score 2):

I could find [this flight](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/KAC175) Kuwait Airways flight 175, an A330-200 flying from Geneva to Frankfurt on a 3 per week basis..

Comment: After opening a link, you have provided, I can clearly see that KAC175 is in fact Kuwait->Frankfurt->Geneva. So, it seems, you're only naming last leg of that route. Good question, if you can purchase a ticket only on this route?