# Shortest A380 route from Frankfurt

Tags: air-travel, factoids, aircraft, fra

Narrowing [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/78022/15281), I'd like to ask, what is the shortest route from Frankfurt served by Airbus A380? Or, if there is any non-intercontinental flight served by this type of plane?

Lufthansa is preferred, but can be any airline that operates A380 routes from Frankfurt on as short route as possible.

Answers to the [original question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/78022/15281) (more wide) question did not bring anything related to A380.

I'm aware of British Airways flight BA0903 from Frankfurt to London Heathrow, [temporarily served by A380](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58AryokIROE), but that doesn't answer my question, because this route is no longer served by A380.

Comment: I think the winner is Frankfurt - Dubai on Emirates. It should be slightly shorter than the Frankfurt - New York route.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid "slightly"? :>

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say by 30 or 45 minutes =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this page; https://www.iflya380.com/content/A380_love/a380-destinations.html

It is supposed to show destinations served by each airline that flies the A380.  Not sure how up-to-date it is.

Most everything flown by an A380 is long haul, any short haul is likely temporary, simply to break in a new aircraft or  give crew a little training before going long haul (though crew training reason is usually only for the first couple of aircraft of a type for that airline, not every new aircraft).

Answer (score 8):

Every A380 route ever flown appears to be on http://a380flights.net/ and DXB is the shortest regularly scheduled flight on that site. The odd shorter flight such as FRA-LHR and FRA-PMI have happened in the past.

There doesn't appear to be any short fifth-freedom A380 flights from FRA, unlike, say FRA-MAD on a 787 on LA.